Using pyautocad, how do i change mesh properties(color)
In pyautocad, I created a cube using a 3d mesh and matrix but I can't figure out how to change the mesh's color.
manually changing mesh color(https://i.sstatic.net/xRoyH.png)
Tried looking for module methods to change color but couldn't find anything.

post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly .
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
how to ask

Normally you would want to assign the object to a layer, Then set the layer to a color
But you can set the color directly to the entity
Not pyautocad per se, this is using win32com
import traceback
from pyrx_impx import Rx, Ge, Gi, Db, Ap, Ed, Ax

def PyRxCmd_doit() -> None:
    try:
        axApp = Ax.getApp()
        axDoc = axApp.ActiveDocument
        Ax.IAcadEntity
    
        # (IAcadEntity, Point)
        axEntRes = axDoc.Utility.GetEntity("Pick an it")
        axEnt: Ax.IAcadEntity= axEntRes[0]
    
        # color index red
        axEnt.color = 1
    
        # TrueColor green
        acColor = Ax.AcadAcCmColor()
        acColor.SetRGB(34,139,34)
        axEnt.TrueColor = acColor
    
    except Exception as err:
        traceback.print_exception(err)


Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. I didn't really find much documentation about autoCAD so this is really useful. Thanks!
